# Why the point returned by clicked signal of QLineSeries is not in QLineSeries.point()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtcharts

I am using pyqt5 and pyside2, but not c++ qt.

I tried this:

```
series = QLineSeries()
series.append(QPointF(x, y))
series.clicked.connect(lambda p: print(p in series.point()))
```

Actually every time I click on the point, the returned point is not in series (False), but according to qt5 document

> This signal is emitted when the user triggers a mouse event by clicking the point point in the chart.

To my understand, the point in the chart also should in the series.

So how could I get a point in series by click?

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

To understand what the function of the QLineSeries clicked signal is, I will use the following example: I will construct the series using the points (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1) and (4, 0).

If you look at the signal it will be emitted when the line that connects the points with which the series was built is pressed(e.g (2.5, 0.5)), therefore the pressed points do not coincide with what the `points()` (or `pointsVector()`) return.

#### Solution:

If you only want to detect when you press the points that are used to build the series then you can calculate the distance to check if it is less than a threshold and then return the point:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


def verify(series, p, threshold=0.05):
    distances = [
        (QtGui.QVector2D(p - x).length(), x)
        for x in series.pointsVector()
        if QtGui.QVector2D(p - x).length() < threshold
    ]
    if distances:
        p = min(distances)
        return p[1]


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()

    series << QtCore.QPointF(0, 0) << QtCore.QPointF(1, 1) << QtCore.QPointF(
        2, 0
    ) << QtCore.QPointF(3, 1) << QtCore.QPointF(4, 0)

    series.setPointsVisible()

    chart = QtCharts.QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.createDefaultAxes()
    chartView = QtCharts.QChartView(chart)
    chartView.show()
    chartView.resize(640, 480)

    def on_clicked(p):
        x = verify(series, p)
        if x is not None:
            print("clicked: ", x)

    series.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I did in my app is that after I init a QPointF, I attached some other property to it, then add it into QLineSeries, when I click the QLineSeries point in chart, I want to know the attached property of the point I clicked. So do you mean than the only way is to find the closest QPointF in QLineSeries.point() to the point returned by clicked signal by calculating euclidian distance and no way to get the point in QLineSeries.point()  directly?

Comment: @fgg1991 No, there is not.

Comment: Also yes I did noticed the coordinate of the point returned by clicked signal is always a little different to the actually added QPointF. Like I run your code and also print p in method on_clicked, the difference is the 3rd decimal in coor.

Comment: @fgg1991 Floats are not accurate (read IEEE 752 standard) so there will always be errors. IMHO you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: A little disappointted. What I did before is to use matplotlib and pyqt backend api as chart widget and also use euclidian distance to get the property of the point that is clicked. I was thinking pychart could help me to get the point directly but it cannot. So do you know any other plot library like matplotlib could work with pyqt and achieve what I want?

Comment: @fgg1991 All libraries work on floating point and all will have that error, I don't see a compelling reason why you don't want to use Euclidean distance. What disadvantages does it have? Why don't you want to use that method?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just noticed it. XY problem. The actual question should be how to get the point object itself when clicking in chart rather than getting the coordinate and calculation required to get the point.

Comment: just not elegant just kidding. In my mind, what I want is 1. define a point object, 2 give it some property, 3 plot library help to display it in chart directly, 4 click in chart return this object directly, not a coordinate so no need to calculate. Could you tell me why no library tried to implement in this way but to consider coordinate rather than point obj itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210817/discussion-between-fgg1991-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @fgg1991 In general, this functionality is not required. From what I understand you is that you associate to each point a data and when you press on that point you want to obtain that information. Am I correct?

Comment: One more reason I prefer point itself rather than euclidean distance is that, when x/y value is very different to x/y screen pixel (for example y axis 1 is 20 pixel on screen while x axis 1 is just 1 pixel), the closest point chosed by euclidean is wrong.

Comment: I add some modification to your verify method, comparing to QVector2D(p - x).length(), I use QVector2D(chart.mapToPosition(p) - chart.mapToPosition(x)).length() to avoid this problem.